# File Output Netlogo

Tags: file, process, netlogo

I have so set `generateOutput` process and in every tick this process has to save the `decision` and `payoff` of the agents in the `txt` file.
 I code it so:

```
to generateOutput

  file-open "Sellers-Buyers.txt"
  file-print "tick step, decision, payoff_seller and payoff_buyer"

end
```

But I think there have to be some additions. Have i to add some new codes or?
best regards

Comment: What happens when you try it?  Does it do what you want?  Does your code make sense given the documentation in the NetLogo Dictionary on these commands?

Comment: it prints in file just the names of the values which I wrote above. but I need the numbers not the names.

Comment: Great.  Now you've told me what output you wanted, and why the code that you listed in the question doesn't do that.  You've also told me that the names inside the quotation marks are names of variables holding numbers.  (However, "tick step" is not the name of a variable.  Is it supposed to be "tick_step"?)  This is all crucial information that was left out of the original question.

Comment: I changed it so 

to generateOutput

  file-open "Sellers-Buyers.txt"
  file-print " decision, payoff_seller and payoff_buyer"

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `decision`, `payoff_seller`, and `payoff_buyer` are variables, you can do this if you want each value on a different line in the file:

```
file-open "Sellers-Buyers.txt"
file-print decision
file-print payoff_seller
file-print payoff_buyer
file-close
```

Note the `file-close` in the last line.

Or if you want all of the information on one line, with commas in between, you can replace the file-print lines above with:

```
file-type decision
file-type ", "
file-type payoff_seller
file-type ", "
file-type payoff_buyer
file-type "\n"
```

Or you could do the same thing in one line like this:

```
file-print (word decision ", " payoff_seller ", " payoff_buyer)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like `file-print (word tick ", " decision ", " payoff_seller " and " payoff_buyer)`

Comment: So I need to see "decision" and "payoff" value of my turtles in this txt file, but the codes that I tried just print the word decision and payoff in that file

Comment: Pay attention to the exact placement of quotation marks and commas in Bryan's answer.